# Post predefined data to twitter

Tags: php, html, twitter

I am trying to get the text from value="" in my form into the php variable $_POST['twitter'] but I keep getting a blank and if I remove isset, I get an undefined error.

```
<?php
//$twitter=(isset($_POST['twitter']));
var_dump($_POST);
?>

<form method="post" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="twitter" value="My Posting Text">Would you like to send to Twitter?<br>
</form>

<div id="custom-tweet-button">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share?" id="my_twitter_id" data-show-screen-name="false" data-url="https://nyctelecomm.com" data-text="<?php echo $_POST['twitter']; ?>" data-counturl="null" class="twitter-share-button" target="_blank" data-count="horizontal" data-lang="en" data-via="NYCTelecomm.com">Tweet</a>
</div>
    <script language="javascript" type='text/javascript'>
                !function (d, s, id)
                {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (!d.getElementById(id))
                    {
                        js = d.createElement(s);
                        js.id = id;
                        js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }
                }
                (document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
     </script>
```

Comment: Is your `<form>` being submitted? Cause right now it seems like it isn't, which means you'll have to use jQUery `onchange` to post to said php script for processing.

Comment: @dbh adjusted $_POST['twitter'] and moved method="$_POST" into form tag. I still get an undefined error for 'twitter' and the use of an isset makes my tweet js button disappear.

Comment: what are these `method` and `action` attributes on the second `checkbox`?

Comment: @akonsu confusion. step 2. I removed it.

Comment: The following use of isset makes the submit/tweet js button disappear and is thought to solve the issue. It just created a new issue.  http://bpaste.net/show/ebmdQpoD7KMgLZvGBrrz/

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @akonsu NULL   ->  array(0) { }  , with or without the isset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your form is submitting.

Give this a try:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_twitter'])) {
        // should set here
        $twitter=(isset($_POST['twitter']));

        var_dump($_POST);
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="twitter" value="My Posting Text">Would you like to send to Twitter?<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_twitter" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php
    // This will only show if $twitter has been set with the post data
    if(isset($twitter)) :
?>
<div id="custom-tweet-button">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share?" id="my_twitter_id" data-show-screen-name="false" data-url="https://nyctelecomm.com" data-text="<?php echo $_POST['twitter']; ?>" data-counturl="null" class="twitter-share-button" target="_blank" data-count="horizontal" data-lang="en" data-via="NYCTelecomm.com">Tweet</a>
</div>
    <script language="javascript" type='text/javascript'>
                !function (d, s, id)
                {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (!d.getElementById(id))
                    {
                        js = d.createElement(s);
                        js.id = id;
                        js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }
                }
                (document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
     </script>

<?php 
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that did show data  ->  array(2) { ["twitter"]=> string(15) "My Posting Text" ["submit_twitter"]=> string(6) "Submit" } and Yes she works like a champ now! I just removed the var_dump and the twitter button passed the value. Thank you!